# Apache / Tomcat / mod_jk when you use Webjars ... is it possible?

Tags: apache, tomcat, webjars

I have a java web application which use Webjars (client-side web libraries (e.g. jQuery & Bootstrap) packaged into JAR (Java Archive) files, see http://www.webjars.org/).
If i use only Tomcat, it works fine.

But i want to put an Apache server in front of the Tomcat (with mod_jk) to serve the static content. How can i configure Apache to do it ? the static content is into jars files !

thks.

Answer (score 0):

In this case Apache is just a proxy for whatever Tomcat serves.  So it **should just work**.

Comment: I agree with you if Apache is just a proxy. But, it seems to me that, in a production environnement, it's a best practice that Apache serve the static content to the client and forward the others requests to tomcat. no ?
In this case, i don't see what is the best way to do that with webjars. Maybe i missed something.

Comment: You can setup Apache to be a caching proxy.  Here is a blog I did that might be helpful: http://www.jamesward.com/2014/04/29/optimizing-static-asset-loading-with-play-framework  It uses Play Framework but the ideas are the same with Tomcat.